# how to install CameraView

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, camera-view

I wanted to use an Android Camera Library called CameraView,
https://natario1.github.io/CameraView/about/install. Its documentation says use
`api 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.6.1'`
 but what does that mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line in the dependencies section of build.gradle(Module:app) file